# MySQL SELECT CASE WHEN fetch speed

Tags: mysql, case

Im using a CASE WHEN within a MySQL SELECT statement

```
case 
    when R1 = risk and R2 = risk then 2 
    when R1 = risk xor R2 = risk then 1
    else 0 
end 
as score
```

However this is increasing the fetch time from 0.5s to 2.5s.

Is there a modification or alternative to the CASE WHEN that performs faster?

Comment: 'risk' is a constant and R1 and R2 are variables.

Comment: these are the possible cases: R1 = risk AND R2 = risk, R1 = risk AND R2 =/= risk, R1 =/= risk AND R2 = risk, R1 =/= risk AND R2 =/= risk

Comment: What else is in your query?

Comment: Why is `XOR` here? How could `risk` simultaneously be two different things unless those two things were identical? You're testing that `R1=R2` and `A1!=A2`.

Comment: because either R1 or R2 could = risk

Comment: @ tadman pls see 3rd comment - R1=R2 but R1!=risk - can you suggest an indexable way of making the case statement

Comment: sorry - i noticed 2nd when clause was misspelled - i'll rewrite question to correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing a query it's important to consider the "sargability" of a predicate - which is to say if the query can use an index or not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

> In relational databases, a condition (or predicate) in a query is said to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index to speed up the execution of the query. The term is derived from a contraction of Search ARGument ABLE.

Unfortunately the `XOR` operator is not generally sargable - so your database cannot use an index on `risk` to speed up the query, instead it has to check every record and recompute the answer - not good!

Instead you should simply return the `risk` value and perform the computation in your client code.

Comment: is there an alternative method that replicates xor that can be used within the query that permits indexing?